# "systemctl" command doesn't work on centos with docker

Tags: docker

I use docker with centos 8.
How can i use systemctl command in dockerfile please ?
When i install an app it needs systemctl.
I have an error:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

I build docker like this:

```
docker build -t myapp:11 .
```

Same when i try in container:

```
docker run -it --privileged app:11 /bin/bash
```

Thank you.

## docker build -t nuance:11 .

## docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN nuance:11 /bin/bash

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM centos:latest
USER root

RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum clean all
    
RUN yum -y install \
    java-11-openjdk-devel \
    perl-Data-Dumper \
    redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 \
    glibc.x86_64 \
    glibc.i686 \
    libstdc++.x86_64 \
    libstdc++.i686 \
    openssl \
    libgcc \
    libgcc.i686 \
    libaio.x86_64 \
    libaio.i686 \
    libnsl.i686 \
    ncurses-libs \
    httpd.x86_64 \
    unzip \
    -x postfix \
    -x mariadb-libs \
    zlib.i686 \
    zlib.x86_64

WORKDIR /tmp

COPY Nuance_Speech_Suite-11.0.10-x86_64-linux.tgz ./Nuance_Speech_Suite-11.0.10-x86_64-linux.tgz
COPY NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0.i686-linux.tar.gz ./languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0.i686-linux.tar.gz
COPY NVE_fr_FR_audrey-ml_xpremium-2.1.0_linux.zip ./languages/NVE_fr_FR_audrey-ml_xpremium-2.1.0_linux.zip
COPY NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-1_linux.zip ./languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-1_linux.zip
COPY NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-2_linux.zip ./languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-2_linux.zip
COPY nuance.lic ./nuance.lic

RUN tar -zxf Nuance_Speech_Suite-11.0.10-x86_64-linux.tgz
RUN tar -zxf languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0.i686-linux.tar.gz
RUN unzip languages/NVE_fr_FR_audrey-ml_xpremium-2.1.0_linux.zip
RUN unzip languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-1_linux.zip
RUN unzip languages/NRec-fr-FR-10.0.0-10.1.0-CumulativePatch-2_linux.zip

WORKDIR /tmp/Nuance_Speech_Suite-11.0.10

RUN ./setup.sh -s -f "/tmp/nuance.lic" -j "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk" -V "/tmp/languages" -I "NLM,NSS"
```

last lines of log

> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: info: Restarting the Nuance License Manager service
> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: info: starting command 'systemctl restart nuance-licmgr'; output sent to log
> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
> Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: info: Command 'systemctl restart nuance-licmgr' returned 1
> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: error: install_postprocessing_nlm_startservices() failed to start services
> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: info: skipping invocation of install_postprocessing_nms() due to previous post processing errors
> 2022-12-16 09:22:11 setup.sh: info: Skipping install_execute_installsuite due to previous errors

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is the error?

Comment: I'm trying to install an application.
Error is : "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"

Comment: Did you find documentation anywhere telling you this _would_ work? It's _possible_ to run some (simpler) init systems in docker, but it's never been a good idea.

Comment: No, I do not find. ok I did not understand what the dockers are for then.
I have an application that installs 3 services. If I can't use systemctl it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run `systemctl` in a Dockerfile at all.  More broadly, commands like `systemctl` or `service` don't work well in Docker, and you should restructure your container to avoid them.

For `systemctl` more specifically, it tries to connect to the `systemd` daemon.  In a Dockerfile, each `RUN` step occurs in a new container, and like other containers, that container *only* runs the one `RUN` command; it does not run `systemd` or any other typical Linux daemons.  Furthermore, at the end of the `RUN` line, the filesystem is persisted but any other changes are lost, so even if you `systemctl start` something successfully, the image won't contain a running process.

More generally I'd recommend avoiding `systemd` in Docker.  A minimal init system like `tini` can be a good idea for some problems like reaping zombie processes; if you must run multiple processes in one container and really can't refactor it then `supervisord` can fill this need.  A typical `systemd` installation will want to configure kernel parameters, start terminal logins, mount filesystems, and configure the network, all of which are basically impossible in Docker; it will capture the main process's stdout so `docker logs` doesn't work.

Aim for your container to only have one process.  Don't run an init system at all if you don't need to.  Don't try to "start a service", just run the program you're trying to build in the foreground as the one thing the container does.

```bash
FROM some-base-image
RUN a command to install the software
CMD the_program
# with no `systemctl` anywhere
```

Comment: thank you but I can't modify the installation.
look at my dockerfile

Comment: The Dockerfile you added into the question doesn't seem to include any direct invocation of `systemctl`?  If you can't modify the script, I'm not clear what the programming-related question is; you may need to contact the other software's author, or run this in a heavier-weight environment like a virtual machine that is able to run systemd.

Answer (score -1):

if you are facing following error when running docker -

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'
```

or

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Run following commands

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

The reason is that you are trying to use systemd command to manage services on Linux but your system doesn't use systemd and (most likely) using the classic SysV init (sysvinit) system.
run following command to confirm if its above case

```
$ ps -p 1 -o comm=
init
```

so now you check again the status using

```
$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

you can start docker using the following command

```
sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

for more detail pls refer following link
https://linuxhandbook.com/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd/

| Systemd command | Sysvinit command |
| --- | --- |
| systemctl start service_name | service service_name start |
| systemctl stop service_name | service service_name stop |
| systemctl restart service_name | service service_name restart |
| systemctl status service_name | service service_name status |
| systemctl enable service_name | chkconfig service_name on |
| systemctl disable service_name | chkconfig service_name off |